# Should an include statement solution be used for storing and retrieving multiple instances of common code

Tags: php, include, eval

I use include statements to share common snippets of php code between different files.  Most of my snippet files contain around 10 to 20 lines of code, but some can get up to several hundred lines long.  As my project grows, so too does the number of snippet files; and file management becomes an issue.

My calling files don't usually use more than 3 or 4 include statements, but when I get to a point where my includes directory has more than 30 snippet files, I question whether using include statements is the best solution for storing and retrieving multiple instances of common code.

Most of my calling files are already making a mysql database connection, so another solution could be to put the the common code into a table and use the eval() function after I retrieve it.  However, I'm concerned whether this creates a security issue.

I am also tempted to throw the entire collection of common code into a single file and call it with function statements, but I don't know whether consolidating the files into one would degrade performance.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: EVERY include() calls incurs a penalty where PHP has to reach out to the disk, locate the file, open/read it, parse it, etc... At some nebulous point that cost will outweigh the cost of loading/parsing a few kbytes of extra/unnecessary code . Where that cutover is, depends on your server: disk speed, cpu speed, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you use classes, use an autoloader. PSR-0 is a good way to go here: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/.